# Nginx reverse proxy with dynamic basehref?

Tags: angular, nginx, proxy, internationalization, reverse-proxy

I have built an i18n app with Angular 9. My api is proxied with the **/api/** url. But since i added i18n, proxy doesnt work anymore.
Rq: (**Angular** add /fr/ or /en/ to the url because i add --baseHref flag on compilation)

I want to know **how can i tell to my proxy to add the dynamic basehref** of my app to the proxy url ?
Exemple : How to transform *GET myapp.com/fr/api/jobs* to *GET myapp.com/api/jobs* ?

So i have this nginx configuration :

```
location /fr/ { 
      autoindex on;
      try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /fr/index.html;
  }

  location /en/ {
      autoindex on;
      try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /en/index.html;
  }

  # Default to FR
  location / {
      # Autoindex is disabled here + the $uri$args/ is missing from try_files
      try_files $uri$args /fr/index.html;
  }

# Proxy to API call
  location */api/ {
    proxy_pass http://rest-api:9000;
  }
```

I'm trying to listen everythin before /api/ but this doesnt work...

Comment: Try adding `~` for regex match: `location ~ .*/api/ {..}`.

Comment: Ok i'll try this right now. So adding `~.*/` will listen to any character before /api/ and then redirect to rest-api:9000 with only /api/ ?

Comment: I can't use multiline markdown in a commend, so I'll drop an answer instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this location:

```
  location ~ .*/api/(.*) {
    proxy_pass http://rest-api:9000/api/$1;
  }
```

This is a regex location that match any URI with `/api/` anywhere in it. For example it will work on:

```
example.com/api/foo/bar
example.com/api/
example.com/something/api/foo/bar
```

There is a capture group `(.*)` to record whatever was after `/api/`. It is saved as a positional variable `$1` (because it's the first and only capture group in the expression). Using it you can build an exact path to your API backend:

```
proxy_pass http://rest-api:9000/api/$1;
```

It will turn the examples above into:

```
proxy_pass http://rest-api:9000/api/foo/bar
proxy_pass http://rest-api:9000/api/
proxy_pass http://rest-api:9000/api/foo/bar
```

**Update**: When you use a regex variable `$1` in `proxy_pass` you have to build full URL manually. If your URL can contain arguments (like `?foo=bar`) you need to add `$is_args$args`. '$is_args' is responsible for adding `?` if there are any arguments and '$args' are the actual arguments. The full path will be like this:

```
proxy_pass http://rest-api:9000/api/$1$is_args$args
```

**Bonus**: you can use this simple server to see how NGINX will interpret the configuration:

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  location ~ .*/api/(.*) {
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    return 200 http://api-server:9000/api/$1;
  }
}
```

Access any path with `/api/` in it and you will see in your browser how your current location is interpreted.

Comment: Ok thank you for the exemple. It's exactly what's i'm tried to do since a week... Thank you again.
But now, all my relative path like "../assets/" stored in my json items fails due to baseHref :')
Have a good day and thank you again

Comment: @Kubadev glad to help. Not sure if it'll be of any help to you but you can capture the preceding string as well with another `(.*)`. You can then pass it as args or something like that.

Comment: Hi, again me. With this exemple : `/en/api/family/f/c?fid=7&fid=1`, it seems the `?` isn't understand by `$1` variable. Thanks again

Comment: Oh well, actually i can do this : `proxy_pass http://rest-api:9000/api/$1$is_args$args` :)

Comment: Or `proxy_pass http://rest-api:9000/api/$1$request_uri`

Comment: @Kubadev if you made your location `~ (.*)/api/(.*)`, the preceding string will be `$1` and the following will be `$2`. You didn't forget to put curly braces, did you?

Comment: I made my location `location ~ .*/api/(.*) {proxy_pass http://rest-api:9000/api/$1; }`. I don't think i forget curly braces! All my request works, except the one containing query parameters likes `/api/path/services?fid=1&?fid=2`. Code 200, but empty arrays. I think this is because the rules don't understand parameters yet without $request_uri ? Or is the same as $1 ?

Comment: @Kubadev sorry I was thinking you're still working on prefix. Request arguments can be added with `?$args`. `$1` contains only location with no arguments in it. I've also added 'bonus content' to my question so you can experiment with some level of comfort :)

Comment: Actually  `$is_args$args` is better, so use it.

Comment: No problem! Thanks again for the help. So my location should looks : `location ~ .*/api/(.*) {proxy_pass http://rest-api:9000/api/$1$is_args_$args; }` ? :) Oh! Thanks again for the bonus content !!

Comment: ok hehe, just updated k8s but unfortunatly since i added `$is_args$args` next to `$1`, all api call result to 502. :') A great another day ahead of me!

Comment: You such a good developer. Thanks again for Bonus, Update, and times :)